# "Please specify a shipping method." while making order programmatically magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i am building order programmatically in magento while using multi-shipping checkout. Every thing is working fine i am stuck at point i am using two shipping methods

> Flat Rate
>
> Matrixrate

when i choose flatrate orders are creating and every thing is fine but when i am choosing matrixrate its not working giving me error

> Please specify a shipping method.

because this function

> getShippingRateByCode

returns false here is the code in this function

```
public function getShippingRateByCode($code)
{
    foreach ($this->getShippingRatesCollection() as $rate) {
        if ($rate->getCode() == $code) {
            return $rate;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have found that in **$code** the method is matrixrate but in **$rate->getCode()** the method is flatrate that's why if is not working.
can you please tell me why   $rate->getCode() have flatrate even i select matrixrate.

Answer (score 0):

I have add a single shipping method "test_methode" as below:

```
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($shipingAddress);
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod('test_methode');
```

May be this can help you.